# get value from popup page and insert it in parent page codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I had a popup page which had a form with field

```
name,discription , date etc
```

when the form submit successfully popup page close . it work fine till now.

but know i want to get the value of

```
NAME field
```

from popup page and insert it in the parent page form . both page had a different controller . please tell how i procceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of name field in session. So that you can access it even in another controller.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: yes we can do it like this but we don't want to refresh the parent page . we session not work here ?

Comment: Are you using custom modal windows or native javascript popup?